# Select max(id) but need more row data

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following to select the last event a user added

```
SELECT MAX(user_event_id) from user_events where user_id = 63
```

On this row there is also a column `event_title` yet if i try:

```
SELECT MAX(user_event_id), event_title from user_events where user_id = 63
```

the event_title returned does not correspond with the user_event_id

Is it possible to return the last user_event_id and event_title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution doesn't need ORDER BY, which would run slowly if the table is long.

```
SELECT user_event_id, event_title
FROM user_events
WHERE user_event_id = (SELECT MAX(user_event_id)
                       FROM user_events
                       WHERE user_id = 63)
AND user_id = 63   -- This clause not needed if user_event_id is unique
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT user_event_id, event_title 
from user_events 
where user_id = 63
order by user_event_id desc
limit 1
```

Most DBMS does not allow to include **event_title** into field list (like author did) because it is not used for grouping and not aggregate function. But mysql does, often with unexpected result.

**UPDATE**:
This query returns only one record if there are several records with the same min user_event_id for the user. So it addresses slightly different problem, than solution of Barry Brown - which return all records with equal user_event_id.